# How to choose columns if they do not contain "NA" in the rows when using pivot longer

Tags: r, contains

I am trying to use the pivot longer function, except for my `date-time` column, and except for the columns that have `"NA"`'s in them. Previously I was using this code because instead of choosing not to pivot columns with `NA`'s I was choosing not to pivot with columns that had the name `stationary` in it's title.

```
results <-
  as_tibble(LaHave_WA2021) %>%
  # Pivot non-stationary loggers
  pivot_longer(
    -c(Date_Time_GMT_3, ends_with("Stationary")), #this is the line I need to change
    names_to = "response",
    values_to = "y"
  )
```

I was thinking of using `!contains`, but I think that is looking if the column name (not the values within it) does not contain `NA`, for e.g.

```
results <-
  as_tibble(LaHave_WA2021) %>%
  # Pivot non-stationary loggers
  pivot_longer(
    -c(Date_Time_GMT_3, !contains("NA")), #changed to contains here
    names_to = "response",
    values_to = "y"
  )
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

here is a sample of my datafram

```
structure(list(Date_Time_GMT_3 = structure(c(1622552400, 1622553300, 
1622554200, 1622555100, 1622556000, 1622556900), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "EST"), X20822244_27LH_Stationary = c(13.173, 
13.269, 13.269, 13.269, 13.269, 13.269), X20874232_B2LH_Stationary = c(14.517, 
14.517, 14.517, 14.517, 14.517, 14.517), X20874286_X1LH_Stationary = c(13.558, 
13.558, 13.558, 13.654, 13.654, 13.75), X2322844_X1LH_AIR = c(12.11, 
12.207, 12.304, 12.401, 12.401, 12.594), X20817728_X3LH_Stationary = c(14.709, 
14.709, 14.709, 14.709, 14.804, 14.804), X20676884_X3LH_U_StationaryCompare = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), X20819743_X6LH_Stationary = c(15.282, 
15.091, 15.282, 15.091, 14.996, 15.187), X20676900_50LH_U = c(12.207, 
12.207, 12.207, 12.207, 12.207, 12.207), X20822214_73LH_U = c(12.401, 
12.304, 12.304, 12.304, 12.304, 12.401), X20676887_44LH_U = c(11.722, 
11.722, 11.722, 11.722, 11.722, 11.722), X20822223_46LH_U = c(12.401, 
12.401, 12.401, 12.401, 12.497, 12.497), X20874231_56LH_U = c(15.282, 
15.187, 15.187, 15.187, 15.187, 15.187), X20874287_86LH_U = c(11.722, 
11.722, 11.722, 11.722, 11.819, 11.819), X20874298_71LH_U = c(12.69, 
12.594, 12.594, 12.594, 12.594, 12.594), X20874309_51LH_U = c(12.594, 
12.594, 12.69, 12.69, 12.69, 12.787), X20676887_X2LH_S = c(16.9674670250765, 
16.9674670250765, 16.9674670250765, 16.9674670250765, 17.0422755866248, 
17.0422755866248), X20819831_11LH_S = c(12.8720832098541, 12.8720832098541, 
12.8720832098541, 12.8720832098541, 12.8720832098541, 12.8720832098541
), X20822214_X4LH_S = c(17.5627317604855, 17.4148767005618, 17.5627317604855, 
17.4148767005618, 17.3413362257306, 17.4891912856543), X20822223_B3LH_S = c(19.4491451568519, 
19.4491451568519, 19.4491451568519, 19.4491451568519, 19.4491451568519, 
19.4491451568519), X20874231_62LH_S = c(15.271566973638, 15.271566973638, 
15.271566973638, 15.271566973638, 15.352583630419, 15.352583630419
), X20874298_B5LH_S = c(16.18926182318, 16.0019888653251, 16.18926182318, 
16.0019888653251, 15.9088426297429, 16.0961155875977), X20874309_B4LH_S = c(16.4017335880702, 
16.4017335880702, 16.4017335880702, 16.4017335880702, 16.4017335880702, 
16.4017335880702), X20676900_X5LH_S = c(13.1517913863509, 13.1517913863509, 
13.1517913863509, 13.2570884294554, 13.2570884294554, 13.3623854725599
), X20874287_58LH_U = c(12.913887422357, 12.913887422357, 12.913887422357, 
13.0000515069191, 13.0000515069191, 13.0862155914811), X20676900_54LH_S = c(11.405378599334, 
11.405378599334, 11.405378599334, 11.5019113471797, 11.5019113471797, 
11.5984440950255), X20819831_B1LH_S = c(16.3133453742116, 16.3133453742116, 
16.3133453742116, 16.3133453742116, 16.3133453742116, 16.3133453742116
), X20822214_76LH_S = c(12.704891245155, 12.704891245155, 12.704891245155, 
12.7949447496304, 12.7949447496304, 12.8849982541058), X20874231_31LH_S = c(13.8728743143662, 
13.8728743143662, 13.8728743143662, 13.8728743143662, 13.9537598661273, 
13.9537598661273), X20874298_55LHA_S = c(15.4572659453372, 15.2879259022681, 
15.4572659453372, 15.2879259022681, 15.2036991792756, 15.3730392223447
), X20822223_55LHB_S = c(15.4378290607062, 15.2700462580074, 
15.4378290607062, 15.2700462580074, 15.1865940786546, 15.3543768813534
), X20874287_70LH_S = c(16.429020745951, 16.429020745951, 16.429020745951, 
16.429020745951, 16.505152496343, 16.505152496343), X20874309_69LH_S = c(12.693578938679, 
12.693578938679, 12.693578938679, 12.7722769090551, 12.7722769090551, 
12.8509748794313), X10694645_20LH_S = c(14.1427870767824, 14.2416357374311, 
14.2416357374311, 14.2416357374311, 14.2416357374311, 14.2416357374311
), X20676900_57LH_S = c(14.4625399465288, 14.5352849038226, 14.5352849038226, 
14.5352849038226, 14.5352849038226, 14.5352849038226), X20819831_3LH_S = c(13.7114345882018, 
13.8015037541561, 13.8015037541561, 13.8015037541561, 13.8015037541561, 
13.8015037541561), X20822223_4LH_S = c(14.5467983081353, 14.628865937343, 
14.628865937343, 14.628865937343, 14.628865937343, 14.628865937343
), X20874231_79LH_S = c(13.5990052211839, 13.5990052211839, 13.5990052211839, 
13.5990052211839, 13.5990052211839, 13.5990052211839), X20874287_67LH_S = c(16.7919014799185, 
16.7919014799185, 16.7919014799185, 16.7919014799185, 16.8571822586659, 
16.8571822586659), X20874298_47LH_S = c(13.1257581381716, 13.2199456919256, 
13.2199456919256, 13.2199456919256, 13.2199456919256, 13.2199456919256
), X20874309_74LH_S = c(14.2622498116035, 14.2622498116035, 14.2622498116035, 
14.2622498116035, 14.3482543034687, 14.3482543034687), X20676887_49LH_S = c(12.3859934583537, 
12.3859934583537, 12.3859934583537, 12.461253579944, 12.461253579944, 
12.5365137015344)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

We may `select` to remove the columns that have all NAs, and this will remove those columns as part of the output

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
LaHave_WA2021 %>%
   select(where(~ !all(is.na(.x)))) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -c(Date_Time_GMT_3), names_to = 'response', 
   values_to = 'y')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 240 × 3
   Date_Time_GMT_3     response                      y
   <dttm>              <chr>                     <dbl>
 1 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20822244_27LH_Stationary  13.2
 2 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20874232_B2LH_Stationary  14.5
 3 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20874286_X1LH_Stationary  13.6
 4 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X2322844_X1LH_AIR          12.1
 5 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20817728_X3LH_Stationary  14.7
 6 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20819743_X6LH_Stationary  15.3
 7 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20676900_50LH_U           12.2
 8 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20822214_73LH_U           12.4
 9 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20676887_44LH_U           11.7
10 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20822223_46LH_U           12.4
# … with 230 more rows
```

---

If we want to remove the `NA` rows, it is also possible with `values_drop_na = TRUE`

```
LaHave_WA2021 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Date_Time_GMT_3), names_to = 'response', 
   values_to = 'y', values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 240 × 3
   Date_Time_GMT_3     response                      y
   <dttm>              <chr>                     <dbl>
 1 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20822244_27LH_Stationary  13.2
 2 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20874232_B2LH_Stationary  14.5
 3 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20874286_X1LH_Stationary  13.6
 4 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X2322844_X1LH_AIR          12.1
 5 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20817728_X3LH_Stationary  14.7
 6 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20819743_X6LH_Stationary  15.3
 7 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20676900_50LH_U           12.2
 8 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20822214_73LH_U           12.4
 9 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20676887_44LH_U           11.7
10 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20822223_46LH_U           12.4
# … with 230 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
results <-
  as_tibble(LaHave_WA2021) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    -c(Date_Time_GMT_3, where(anyNA)), # or where(~ all(is.na(.)))
    names_to = "response",
    values_to = "y"
  )
```

Output:

```
results[1:10, ]

# A tibble: 10 × 4
   Date_Time_GMT_3     X20676884_X3LH_U_StationaryCompare response                      y
   <dttm>                                           <dbl> <chr>                     <dbl>
 1 2021-06-01 08:00:00                                 NA X20822244_27LH_Stationary  13.2
 2 2021-06-01 08:00:00                                 NA X20874232_B2LH_Stationary  14.5
 3 2021-06-01 08:00:00                                 NA X20874286_X1LH_Stationary  13.6
 4 2021-06-01 08:00:00                                 NA X2322844_X1LH_AIR          12.1
 5 2021-06-01 08:00:00                                 NA X20817728_X3LH_Stationary  14.7
 6 2021-06-01 08:00:00                                 NA X20819743_X6LH_Stationary  15.3
 7 2021-06-01 08:00:00                                 NA X20676900_50LH_U           12.2
 8 2021-06-01 08:00:00                                 NA X20822214_73LH_U           12.4
 9 2021-06-01 08:00:00                                 NA X20676887_44LH_U           11.7
10 2021-06-01 08:00:00                                 NA X20822223_46LH_U           12.4
```

This is excluding columns from pivoting which have any missing values. If you're looking to exclude only columns that only have missing values, you could replace the `where` part with e.g. `where(~ all(is.na(.)))`.

Answer (score 0):

We could use the  `values_drop_na = TRUE` argument:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -Date_Time_GMT_3,
      names_to = "response",
      values_to = "y",
    values_drop_na = TRUE
  )
```

```
  Date_Time_GMT_3     response                      y
   <dttm>              <chr>                     <dbl>
 1 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20822244_27LH_Stationary  13.2
 2 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20874232_B2LH_Stationary  14.5
 3 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20874286_X1LH_Stationary  13.6
 4 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X2322844_X1LH_AIR          12.1
 5 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20817728_X3LH_Stationary  14.7
 6 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20819743_X6LH_Stationary  15.3
 7 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20676900_50LH_U           12.2
 8 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20822214_73LH_U           12.4
 9 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20676887_44LH_U           11.7
10 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20822223_46LH_U           12.4
# … with 230 more rows
```

Another verbose solution is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
with_na <- df %>%
  purrr::map_df(~sum(is.na(.))) %>% 
  select(where(~sum(.) != 0)) %>% 
  colnames()

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -c(Date_Time_GMT_3, with_na),
      names_to = "response",
      values_to = "y"
  ) %>% 
  select(contains("Date"), response, y)
```

```
 Date_Time_GMT_3     response                      y
   <dttm>              <chr>                     <dbl>
 1 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20822244_27LH_Stationary  13.2
 2 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20874232_B2LH_Stationary  14.5
 3 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20874286_X1LH_Stationary  13.6
 4 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X2322844_X1LH_AIR          12.1
 5 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20817728_X3LH_Stationary  14.7
 6 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20819743_X6LH_Stationary  15.3
 7 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20676900_50LH_U           12.2
 8 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20822214_73LH_U           12.4
 9 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20676887_44LH_U           11.7
10 2021-06-01 08:00:00 X20822223_46LH_U           12.4
# … with 230 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```